# Battlefront tie-ins with "The Force Awakens" (Episode VII)

Tags: star-wars, video-games, the-force-awakens

I read on The Internet (TM) that the new Battlefront game has tie-ins with *The Force Awakens*.  Does anyone know what they may be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), where they already have many questions related to Battlefront.

Comment: Movie questions on this site abound.  Arquade may well vote to close it as off-topic, arguing that it belongs here.  It straddles the fence a bit, I admit.  My reason for asking is primarily to understand the story/plot of the movie better, and I was wondering specifics on how a supporting work like the game does that.

Comment: It's true that this site has movie questions, but it seems to me that you were asking if there was any sort of DLC for Battlefront that involve locales from the new movies. (The [Battle of Jakku](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/news/jakku-pre-order-offer) is one such DLC that is out already). I'm not really sure how this site is a better fit for a question about DLC than Arqade.

Comment: Seems on topic to me.

Comment: I agree. This may be on-topic on Arquade, but it is also on-topic here

Answer (score 3):

Yes.... and no (there was one - see below, [but there likely won't be anymore](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/119390/20151224/star-wars-battlefront-doesnt-look-to-be-getting-any-the-force-awakens-dlc.htm) - the theory being that EA is saving TFA content for the next game version, instead of DLC)

1. > There’s one exception: a few weeks after Star Wars: Battlefront makes its way into players’ hands, DICE will release a DLC pack to help bridge the gap between The Return of the Jedi and J.J. Abrams’ new Star Wars film, The Force Awakens. The expansion is called “**The Battle of Jakku,**” and will let players reenact a pivotal battle from Star Wars lore, in which the newly victorious Rebel Alliance takes on one of the last remaining Imperial strongholds.  *([source](http://gamerant.com/star-wars-battlefront-episode-7-dlc-battle-of-jakku/))*

   Electronic Arts' web page for it is: http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/features/battle-of-jakku

   You can see the play on Youtube here:

   Or the official trailer from EA: